# meta_query search names when they have middle initials - PHP, WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, meta-key, codex

I have to build a search form where I search members of the company by their Full Name (First Name + Middle Initial + Last Name). All the names are in this form: **John B. Doe**.

The below code is working on these cases: *John, John B., Doe, B., John B. Doe*, but not working the query search is: *`John Doe`*.

```
 if (isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != -1) {
    $args['meta_query']['name_search']['key'] = "_full_name";
    $args['meta_query']['name_search']['compare'] = "LIKE";
    $args['meta_query']['name_search']['value'] = $_POST['search'];
  }
```

How should I improve the query in order to work with both: the name and surname (John Doe) and the name, surname plus the middle initial (John B. Doe)?

Comment: Actually, WordPress meta queries support `REGEXP` as the `compare` value.. So you could use regular expression search.

Comment: @SallyCJ I've tried with REGEXP as a compare value but it isn't working.

Comment: What is the code you tried with? You were not using the same `value` as it is currently in the question, were you? I mean, keep in mind that special characters like `.` ("dots") need to be properly escaped.

Comment: @SallyCJ, I've tried by replacing the "LIKE" with "REGEXP" and I left it the same as the other parts of the code.

Comment: Well, no wonder it didn't work.. You need to supply a valid regex pattern like `John.*Doe` as the `value`. However, if by "members" you're referring to users in the WordPress users table (`wp_users`), then WordPress actually adds two custom fields (`first_name` and `last_name`) for each user, so you could just use those fields and as for the middle initial, you could use another field, e.g. `middle_initial`, and then you would just query those fields with an `OR` relation..

Comment: @SallyCJ No, the search queries a custom field "_full_name" in which are stored the full names (including first name, last name, and middle initial, e.g John B.Doe). I can't modify the structure since there a lot of data stored in this way.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Anyway, see my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if only WordPress doesn't escape the `%` characters in the `value` (i.e. the search keyword), you could've simply replaced spaces in the search keyword with `%`, hence you'd get a clause like `meta_value LIKE '%John%Doe%'` which would match `John B. Doe`.

So because the `%` in the search keyword is being escaped (which is a good thing, BTW), then you can instead use `REGEXP` (regular expression search) and then replace the spaces with a `.*` which is equivalent to the `%` in a `LIKE` clause.

### Working Example

Replace this in your code:

```php
$args['meta_query']['name_search']['compare'] = "LIKE";
$args['meta_query']['name_search']['value'] = $_POST['search'];
```

with this:

```php
// Build the regular expression pattern.
$list = preg_split( '/ +/', trim( $_POST['search'] ) );
$regex = implode( '.*', array_map( 'preg_quote', $list ) );

// Then set 'compare' to REGEXP and 'value' to the above pattern.
$args['meta_query']['name_search']['compare'] = 'REGEXP';
$args['meta_query']['name_search']['value'] = $regex;
```

Tried & tested working in WordPress 5.7.2, but do take note of the "not multibyte safe" warning in the [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

### Alternate Solution (equivalent to the one above)

*If you want to use `LIKE` and not `REGEXP`, but don't want to end up with potentially lots of meta queries for the same key, then you can:*

Use three search fields, namely first name, last name, and middle initial, and three meta clauses, one for each search field, but all having `key` set to `_full_name`. E.g.

```php
/*
 * Assuming your form contains these:
    <input name="first_name">
    <input name="last_name">
    <input name="middle_initial">
 */

$name_search = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
);

// * okay, this still uses 3 clauses, but it always would be just 3 clauses
foreach ( array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_initial' ) as $name ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST[ $name ] ) ) {
        $name_search[ $name ] = array(
            'key'     => '_full_name',
            'value'   => sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $name ] ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }
}

$args['meta_query']['name_search'] = $name_search;
```

Answer (score 0):

### I can suggest the following solution:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$words  = explode( $search, ' ' );
$words  = array_filter(
    $words,
    function ( $word ) {
        return ! empty( trim( $word ) );
    }
);

foreach ( $words as $index => $word ) {
    $query_name          = "name_search_$index";
    $args['meta_query'][ $query_name ] = [
        'key'     => '_full_name',
        'value'   => $word,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];
}
```

### Code explanation:

1. I split search phrases into words. Words are any sequence of symbols
   between spaces
2. I remove spaces. If your search string is

   ```
   John Doe
   ```

   or

   ```
   John  Doe
   ```

   or

   ```
      John        Doe
   ```

   The search result should be the same.
3. I build multiple queries. Every query corresponds to a single word. If you search John Doe the query builds by 2 queries. Queries count as much as the number of words.

### The problems with this solution:

1. Too many words are too many queries. Too many LIKE-containing queries are too slow.
2. You will get the same result for searching for

   ```
   John Doe
   ```

   and

   ```
   Doe John
   ```

   . The order of the words makes no difference to the result.

---

I recommend using this solution only as a temporary solution.
Good solution - is using Full-Text Search plugins or write Full-Text Search solution
yourself. More details about FullText search you could find on MySQL official page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html